# How to use Jquery to handle dropdown implemented as a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="btn-group btn-grp-uk col-xs-12 ">
    <button id="colorList" type="button" class="btn-phn btn btn-dropdown-white-
    uk dropdown-toggle col-xs-12" data-toggle="dropdown">Red
    </button>
      <ul id="colordrop" class="dropdown-menu col-xs-12 p-l-0">
        <sly data-sly-list.color="${modelobj.list}">
          <li>${color}</li>
        </sly>
      </ul>
</div>
<div>
<p><strong>MONTHLY COST</strong></p>
<h3 id="monthly-price">£35<small>.00</small></h3>
</div>
```

I need help in changing the price in the  tag when a value from the dropdown value is selected. Since the dropdown is implemented as a button which i cannot change can someone help me achieve this.

I have tried this but it is happening on first click of the button itself not the dropdown values. I am trying to get the event trigger on the second click since the first click will open the dropdown and the second click is responsible for option selection from the dropdown.

```
**var count=0;
$( "#colordrop" ).click(function(event){   
    count++;
    if(count%2==0)      
    var colorListData = document.getElementById("colordrop").innerHTML; 
    document.getElementById('monthly-price').innerHTML = colorListData;
});**
```

The actual HTML is:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-grp-uk col-xs-12 ">
    <button type="button" class="btn-phn btn btn-dropdown-white-uk dropdown-toggle col-xs-12" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Default Color <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu col-xs-12 p-l-0">
        <li> <a href="#">Color1</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Color2</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Color3</a> </li>       
        <li> <a href="#">Color4</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-4 text-center ">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 mob-cost">
    <p><strong>MONTHLY COST FROM</strong> </p>
    <h3>&pound;35<small>.00</small></h3> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add more code snippet to your question? It is hard to understand

Comment: I have added the actual HTML and the modified HTML which i am using is the first one.
My requirement is:
On clicking of a dropdown value which is under <li> tags the jquery should be triggered and should change the value inside <h3> tag which is 35.

Comment: what value will be changed in `<h3>`? Set as Color1 ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle a click on each `<li>`, instead of the `<ul>`. I also notice in your HTML that you're missing the ID on the `<ul>` so make sure to add that as well.

```js
$("#colordrop > li").click(function(event){
  var colorListData = $(this).text(); 
  console.log(colorListData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-grp-uk col-xs-12 ">
    <button type="button" class="btn-phn btn btn-dropdown-white-uk dropdown-toggle col-xs-12" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Default Color <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span>
    </button>
    <ul id="colordrop" class="dropdown-menu col-xs-12 p-l-0">
        <li> <a href="#">Color1</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Color2</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Color3</a> </li>       
        <li> <a href="#">Color4</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-4 text-center ">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 mob-cost">
    <p><strong>MONTHLY COST FROM</strong> </p>
    <h3>&pound;35<small>.00</small></h3> </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bf43v8vy/